# How to show non _Atomic implementation as failing?

Tags: c, unit-testing, atomic

I've written some code, using stdatomic.h/C11.

In order to have confidence that I've done it correctly, I've also written a non _Atomic implementation.

The critical operation is reading an _Atomic uint64_t in multiple threads, and updating it if it's old value was zero, or incrementing a pointer if it was zero.

i.e.

```
while (keys[index] != 0 && keys[index] != key) { // skip past collisions
    index++;
}

if (keys[index] == 0) { // empty slot, so claim it
    keys[index] = key;
}
```

The problem is that my non _Atomic code, above, also passes millions of test runs.

This must be because the distance between the checks and the assignment is so small, possibly just a few instructions.

How can I make a test which makes my non _Atomic implementation fail, so that I can prove that my _Atomic implementation stands a good chance of being correct?

Comment: `if (keys[index] == 0) { sleep(10); keys[index] = key; }`

Comment: `clang -O2 -fsanitize=thread` might be a good start, to show race conditions in the non-atomic version.

Comment: Or for manual testing, single-step with a debugger so you can stop one thread somewhere while you single-step other threads, to exercise exactly the race condition you're looking for.  (But that mostly helps if some interleaving of source order is a problem, like even if everything was seq_cst, not with things that require StoreLoad reordering at run-time.)  And of course it's useless for automated unit-testing, other than to find the right place to put a `sleep(1)` or `nanosleep` for a few microseconds; @KamilCuk's suggestion is good, but the sleep time is *way* longer than needed.